# module to parse a simple syntax in python

Tags: python, dictionary

my goal is to read in the file `/etc/os-release` under Linux using Python 2.7.6 and get a dictionary.
that file looks like this in Ubuntu:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.2 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

i want to end up with a dictionary result like this Python code would create:

```
{
'NAME': 'Ubuntu',
'VERSION': '14.04.2 LTS, Trusty Tahr',
'ID': 'ubuntu',
'ID_LIKE': 'debian',
'PRETTY_NAME': 'Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS',
'VERSION_ID': '14.04',
'HOME_URL': 'http://www.ubuntu.com/',
'SUPPORT_URL': 'http://help.ubuntu.com/',
'BUG_REPORT_URL': 'http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/',
}
```

i found a few parsers in the Python library but each parsed other more complex syntax.  i found examples here but all were for more complex syntax an answered how to code a parser.  i am just looking for a module/function that already exists.  if there is none, then, i will just code my own (so i am not looking for code examples unless it is what i should do).  on trouble with this is that **i do not even know a name for this syntax**.  although my current project is to get `/etc/os-release` as a dictionary i expect the need to do this for other data of a like syntax in the future, so my searches are focusing on the syntax, not that file.

i would think something this simple should already exist.

interesting that the Code Sample display for SO highlights it as if the web code here can parse it but that is not Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make your own dict by splitting:

```
with open("/etc/os-release") as f:
    d = {}
    for line in f:
        k,v = line.rstrip().split("=")
        d[k] = v
print(d)
```

If you really want to remove quotes you can use strip:

```
with open("/etc/os-release") as f:
    d = {}
    for line in f:
        k,v = line.rstrip().split("=")
        # .strip('"') will remove if there or else do nothing
        d[k] = v.strip('"') 
print(d)


{'VERSION': '14.04.2 LTS, Trusty Tahr', 'NAME': 'Ubuntu', 'HOME_URL': 'http://www.ubuntu.com/', 'ID': 'ubuntu', 'VERSION_ID': '14.04', 'SUPPORT_URL': 'http://help.ubuntu.com/', 'PRETTY_NAME': 'Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS', 'BUG_REPORT_URL': 'http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/', 'ID_LIKE': 'debian'}
{'BUG_REPORT_URL': 'http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/',
 'HOME_URL': 'http://www.ubuntu.com/',
 'ID': 'ubuntu',
 'ID_LIKE': 'debian',
 'NAME': 'Ubuntu',
 'PRETTY_NAME': 'Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS',
 'SUPPORT_URL': 'http://help.ubuntu.com/',
 'VERSION': '14.04.2 LTS, Trusty Tahr',
 'VERSION_ID': '14.04'}
```

Comment: but it wouldn't be in order.

Comment: the order is not needed ... the goal is a dictionary

Comment: how would this parse the quotes that may or may not be there?

Comment: @Skaperen, what do you mean by *parse the quotes that may or may not be there*?

Comment: Just use an OrderedDict if you want ordering. The quotes in the file will be included in the dict, it's just part of the string.

Comment: Adding `maxsplit = 1` will prevent problems in case the string contains a `=` sign.

Comment: @Mark, won't make a difference if the first `=` comes in the wrong place, an error would be more appropriate. The OP also does not care about order

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: That's true in general, but I think in the case of a config file of this format it is fairly safe to assume the key doesn't contain any `=` characters.

Comment: i just wanted the quotes removed and some lines did not have them.  letting `rstrip()` do it was the **KISS solution**. it did not error if they were absent.

Comment: doing `k,v = line.rstrip('"').split("=")` seems to work.

Comment: @Skaperen, you would need `strip(''"')` to remove from both sides

Comment: A double quote inside single quotes will strip any " from start and end of the string

Answer (score 1):

Padraic Cunningham answer is perfect, i just follow up to answer second part (parse the quotes that can or cannot be there): if you want to strip off all the quotes just add two line to Padraic's code.

```
with open("/etc/os-release") as f:
    d = {}
    for line in f:
        k,v = line.rstrip().split("=")
        if v.startswith('"'):
          v = v[1:-1]
        d[k] = v
print(d)
```

This because we can assume that if the property starts with a double quote it will end the same way. If you want the same behavior also for single quote just put a second condition in OR in the if.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [man page of os-release](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/os-release.html):

> Variable assignment values must be enclosed in double or single quotes if they include spaces, semicolons or other special characters outside of A-Z, a-z, 0-9. Shell special characters ("$", quotes, backslash, backtick) must be escaped with backslashes, following shell style.Lines beginning with "#" shall be ignored as comments.

Every rule specified in the quote above must be considered when you write parser for the file. It is complicated, because it's designed to be executed as a shell script. Implementing this means implementing part of shell.

As for the quotation marks, they have no meaning other than enclosing complicated string thus can be ignored. Another thing you must consider is that split by '=' is not 100% correct because there might be more than one '=' in a single line. Split by the position of first '=' instead.

Comment: `maxsplit=1` should handle `=` in the value.  i don't expect them in names.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be implemented as a simple dict comprehension with modern (3.5+) python:

```
{
    k.lower(): v.strip('\'"')
    for k, v in (
        line.strip().split('=', 1)
        for line in open('/etc/os-release').read().strip().split('\n')
    )
}
```

This generates a dictionary like this

```
{'name': 'Ubuntu',
 'version': '18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)',
 'id': 'ubuntu',
 'id_like': 'debian',
 'pretty_name': 'Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS',
 'version_id': '18.04',
 'home_url': 'https://www.ubuntu.com/',
 'support_url': 'https://help.ubuntu.com/',
 'bug_report_url': 'https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/',
 'privacy_policy_url': 'https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy',
 'version_codename': 'bionic',
 'ubuntu_codename': 'bionic'}
```

Alternatively, I found a namedtuple quite useful:

```
from collections import namedtuple
with open('/etc/os-release') as f:
    keys, values = zip(*[
        (k.lower(), v.strip('\'"'))
        for (k, v) in (
            line.strip().split('=', 1) for line in f.read().strip().split('\n')
        )]
    ) 
r = namedtuple("OSRelease", keys)(*values)
```

this generates a namedtuple with all variables accessible as attributes:

```
[ins] In [1]: from collections import namedtuple 
         ...: with open('/etc/os-release') as f: 
         ...:     keys, values = zip(*[ 
         ...:         (k.lower(), v.strip('\'"')) 
         ...:         for (k, v) in ( 
         ...:             line.strip().split('=', 1) for line in f.read().strip().split('\n') 
         ...:         )] 
         ...:     )  
         ...: r = namedtuple("OSRelease", keys)(*values)                                               

[ins] In [2]: print(r)                                                                                 
OSRelease(name='Ubuntu', version='18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)', id='ubuntu', id_like='debian', pretty_name='Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS', version_id='18.04', home_url='https://www.ubuntu.com/', support_url='https://help.ubuntu.com/', bug_report_url='https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/', privacy_policy_url='https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy', version_codename='bionic', ubuntu_codename='bionic')

[ins] In [3]: print(r.id)                                                                              
ubuntu

[ins] In [4]: print(r.id_like)                                                                         
debian

[ins] In [5]: print(r.version_id)                                                                      
18.04

[ins] In [6]: print(r.ubuntu_codename)                                                                 
bionic
```